# jQuery Star Rating Plugin hover with multiple selections

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, rating

Hi all I have tinkered with this for quite some time and can not figure it out.
I have a review page with 3 rating selections (Quality, Value, Service).
I am using fyneworks jQuery Star Rating Plugin v4.11 and like the idea of the hover over effect that displays the title of the radio input (i.e. Poor, Good, Great).

I am trying to accomplish the following:
Be able to hover over each rating selection and have the title displayed next to it.
Once the rating is selected (clicked) I would like to have the title permanently displayed.
Goole+ uses this kind of functionality.

Here is my code so far

jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.hover-star').rating({
                focus: function (value, link) {
                    var tip = $('#hover-test');
                    tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
                    tip.html(link.title || 'value: ' + value);
                },
                blur: function (value, link) {
                    var tip = $('#hover-test');
                    $('#hover-test').html(tip[0].data || '');
                }

            });
         });
    </script>
```

html

```
<div>
    <p>Service Rating</p>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="1" title="Very poor"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="2" title="Poor"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="3" title="OK"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="4" title="Good"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="5" title="Very Good"/>
    <span id="hover-test" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Value Rating</p>    
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-2" value="1" title="Very poor"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-2" value="2" title="Poor"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-2" value="3" title="OK"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-2" value="4" title="Good"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-2" value="5" title="Very Good"/>
    <span id="hover-test-2" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;"></span>
</div>

<div>
    <p>Quality Rating</p>    
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-3" value="1" title="Very poor"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-3" value="2" title="Poor"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-3" value="3" title="OK"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-3" value="4" title="Good"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-3" value="5" title="Very Good"/>
    <span id="hover-test-3" style="margin:0 0 0 20px;"></span>
</div>
```

I am stuck and do not know to to proceed any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: did you try the code below?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying and pasting. This should do everything youre asking for in this one html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>jQuery Star Rating Plugin v4.11 (2013-03-14)</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<link href='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>


<div class="Clear">&nbsp;</div>
<form id="form1">
<strong style='font-size:150%'>Stackoverflow Test</strong>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="10"> <tr>
<td valign="top" width="">
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="50%">
<div class="Clear">
<div id = "quality" class = "quality">
QUALITY:
</div>
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-1" value="Poor" title="Poor" />
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-1" value="Good" title="Good"/>
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-1" value="Great" title="Great"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="Clear">
<div id = "value" class = "value">
VALUE:
</div>
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-2" value="Poor" title="Poor""/>
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-2" value="Good" title="Good"/>
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-2" value="Great" title="Great"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="Clear">
<div id = "service" class = "service">
SERVICE:
</div>
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-3" value="Poor" title="Poor"/>
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-3" value="Good" title="Good"/>
<input class="star" type="radio" name="test-1-rating-3" value="Great" title="Great"/>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("input[name='test-1-rating-1']").change(radioValueChanged1);
    })

    function radioValueChanged1()
    {
        radioValue = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById("quality").innerHTML = "QUALITY IS <b>"+radioValue+"</b>!";
       // alert(radioValue);
    } 

jQuery(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("input[name='test-1-rating-2']").change(radioValueChanged2);
    })

    function radioValueChanged2()
    {
        radioValue = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = "VALUE IS <b>"+radioValue+"</b>!";
       // alert(radioValue);
    } 

jQuery(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("input[name='test-1-rating-3']").change(radioValueChanged3);
    })

    function radioValueChanged3()
    {
        radioValue = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById("service").innerHTML = "SERVICE IS <b>"+radioValue+"</b>!";
       // alert(radioValue);
    } 

</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Your solution does work but is not quite what I was looking for. I can not vote you up, since my reputation seems to low.

Comment: @239revilo dont worry about any of the voting stuff. Lets just get this working for you - thats really what Stackoverflow is about. Can you describe a bit more of what you are looking for? Ill take it from there.

Comment: Hi Chris... thank you for your help... what I am looking for is  basically the hover over feature of the fyneworks star rating plugin.

Comment: Oh @239revilo I see what you wanted now. I just saw your code and tried it out... Now I get it. Looks very cool!

Comment: with some additions. please look at https://plus.google.com/110567867745504451644/about and click on write review. That is what I would like to copy.

Comment: thank you... yours works but I want the hover over as well as clicked title to be displayed....

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the code like below. It's seems like a hack but it works for now.
I really like how google+ review writing solved this and tried to get as close with this as possible. I am open to any improvements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>jQuery Star Rating Plugin v4.11 (2013-03-14)</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.js' type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<link href='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.hover-star').rating({
                focus: function (value, link) {
                    $("#hover-test").css("color", "#000");
                    var tip = $('#hover-test');
                    tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
                    tip.html(link.title || 'value: ' + value);
                },
                blur: function (value, link) {
                    var tip = $('#hover-test');
                    $('#hover-test').html(tip[0].data || '');
                },

                click: function (value, link) {
                    var tip = $('#hover-test');
                    tip.empty();
                },

                callback: function(value, link){
                    var tip = $('#stick');
                tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
                tip.html(link.title || 'value: ' + value);
                }

            });

            $(".hover-star").click(function () {
                $("#hover-test").css("color", "#ff6a00");

            });
         });
    </script>

<div>
    <p>Service Rating</p>
    <div>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="1" title="Very poor"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="2" title="Poor"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="3" title="OK"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="4" title="Good"/>
    <input class="hover-star" type="radio" name="test-3B-rating-1" value="5" title="Very Good"/>
</div>
    <div id="star-rating" style="position:relative;">
        <div id="stick" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:200px;color:#ff6a00;"></div>
        <div id="hover-test" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:200px;width:250px;background-color:#fff;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
  <br /><br />  

</body></html>
```